# Coincidence of bitwise and and bitwise or operators?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operators, addition

So, while playing with the bitwise AND and bitwise OR operators, I noticed the following:

```c
(a & b) + (a | b) = a + b
```

and there is a corresponding proof which mainly relies on the fact for any two bits x and y,

```
(a,b) = (0,0) --> (a&b, a|b) = (0, 0) = (a, b)
(a,b) = (0,1) --> (a&b, a|b) = (0, 1) = (a, b)
(a,b) = (1,0) --> (a&b, a|b) = (0, 1) = (b, a)
(a,b) = (1,1) --> (a&b, a|b) = (1, 1) = (b, a)
```

Now, I was wondering - is this a mere coincidence, or are these bitwise operations actually used in this way? I don't think that computers actually compute addition in this way, since it would be a recursive definition... but it seems too nice of a property to have been random!

Comment: This is a math question really, not anything specific to a particular language

Answer (score 3):

AND and OR are idempotent and commutative:

```
a & a = a
a | a = a
a & b = b & a
a | b = b | a
```

They also absorb each other:

```
a & (a | b) = a
a | (a & b) = a
```

Thus:

```
a + b = (a | a) + (b & b)
a + b = (a | (a & b)) + (b & (a | b))

(a | a) + (b & b) = (a | (a & b)) + (b & (a | b))
a + b = (a & b) + (a | b)
```

Another way to see it is that, for two bits `x` and `y`, `x + y = x | y` and `x & y = 0` unless both bits are set, and then `x & y` adds the missing bit to `x | y`.

Answer (score 1):

when *a* and *b* value only 0 or 1 it is not surprising to have `(a & b) + (a | b) == a + b`

- having both *a* and *b* valuing 1 `(a & b)` and `(a | b)` value 1, so you do `1+1` on each side of `==`
- else `(a & b)` is obviously 0 so you compare `a|b` and `a+b` while there is no possible carry on `a+b` and in that case *a* and *b* being a boolean do use `+` or `|` is the same

---

Note when *a* and *b* value only 0 or 1 then `a&b` equals `a*b` in all cases

Answer (score 1):

`(a & b) + (a | b) = a + b` is indeed true in general, not just for 0 and 1.

An other way to look at it, is that whenever the bits in `a` and `b` at a particular position are *different* (so one of them is zero and the other is one), then in `(a & b) + (a | b)` the 0 is put on the left hand side of the `+` and the 1 is put on the right hand side. If the bits are the same then it doesn't make any difference.

It's like a more granular form of `min(a, b) + max(a, b)`, at the bit level intead of the word level.

Reordering bits like that has no effect on the sum. Consider that both `a` and `b` are already sums, of the form `a[0] + 2*a[1] + 4*a[2] ...`. `a + b` is a bigger sum, and `(a & b) + (a | b)` merely reordered the terms of that sum.